# How to implement conditional relationship clause in cypher for Spring Neo4j query?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query called from Java (Spring Neo4j) that I'm using, which works.

The basic query is straightfoward - it asks what nodes lead to another node.

The gist of the challenge is that there are a set (of three) items - `contributor`, `tag`, and `source` - that the query might need to filter its results by.

Two of these  - `tag` and `source` - bring with them a relationship that needs to be tested.  But if these are not provided, then that relationship does not need to be tested.

Neo-browser warns me that the query I'm using it will be inefficient, for probably obvious reasons:

```
@Query("MATCH (p:BoardPosition)<-[:PARENT]-(n:BoardPosition)<-[:PARENT*0..]-(c:BoardPosition), 
        (t:Tag), (s:JosekiSource) WHERE 
        id(p)={TargetID} AND 
        ({ContributorID} IS NULL or c.contributor = {ContributorID}) AND 
        ({TagID} IS NULL or ((c)-->(t) AND id(t) = {TagID}) ) AND 
        ({SourceID} IS NULL or ((c)-->(s) AND id(s) = {SourceID}) ) 
         RETURN DISTINCT n"
       )

List<BoardPosition> findFilteredVariations(@Param("TargetID") Long targetId,
                                           @Param("ContributorID") Long contributorId,
                                           @Param("TagID") Long tagId,
                                           @Param("SourceID") Long sourceId);
```

*(Java multi-line query string catenation removed from code for clarity)*

It would appear that this would be more efficient if the conditional inclusion of the relationship-test could be in the MATCH clause itself.   But that does not appear possible.

Is there some in-cypher way I can improve the efficiency of this?

---

FWIW: the Neo4j browser warning is:

> This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns.
>   If a part of a query contains multiple disconnected patterns, this
>   will build a cartesian product between all those parts. This may
>   produce a large amount of data and slow down query processing.

Comment: The best way too experiment is to use the Neo4j browser to do query profiling (prepending the query with EXPLAIN or PROFILE). About the query: the Neo4j way of doing `X IS NULL or X.prop=...` is to use an `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause

Comment: I saw the advice in the warning - "an optional match may help".  But I read about optional match and couldn't see how to apply it here.  If you could formulate that, it might be the actual answer I'm looking for!  Thanks!

Comment: Let's say you have blog posts than can have comments. Doing:
`MATCH (p:Post)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[HAS_COMMENT]-(c:Comment)
RETURN p`
will bring back all the posts, even those without comments

Comment: That is a fantastically helpful way of explaining it!  Thanks!

Comment: ... however, it doesn't seem to supply a solution.   There appears to be no way of saying "if the parameter TagID is NOT null then only return n's that do match the tag" (other than the query as in the question)

Comment: hummm, I see. Unless you really want to do this in cypher, I'd suggest doing a custom repository implementation. By injection a session, you can easily build a custom query according to the input parameters and run it. It would keep the code more readable IMHO